# Spring Data for Redis: when dealing with values, does it only works with StringRedisTemplate?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

When dealing with strings with Spring Data for Redis, I noticed the following behavior:

Given the code below:

```
template.opsForValue().set("person", "value");
```

it only works when I'm using an instance of StringRedisTemplate, and not when I'm using an instance of RedisTemplate. Should'nt it work with RedisTemplate since it aggregates all the operations for all the Redis data types?

Answer (score 1):

StringRedisTemplate is just a specialization of RedisTemplate, so you should be able to use RedisTemplate directly if you prefer, provided that you set all the key/value serializers as is done in the constructor of StringRedisTemplate.

Perhaps you could provide more information about your configuration and what error you are getting?  Also, why is StringRedisTemplate not a desirable option for your use case?

Comment: The only configuration that I changed on the RedisTemplate instance is the injection of the ConnectionFactory, just like in documentation, and it simply doesn't work.
Does I need to add any more dependency to this class?

Comment: You may need to set the key/value and hashkey/hashvalue serializers to an instance of StringRedisSerializer, though the default serializer seems to work for simple strings. What is the error you are getting? And which ConnectionFactory are you using?

Comment: I'm getting no error. It simply doesn't persist the data on the Redis server.

Comment: Try setting the serializers to an instance of StringRedisSerializer as I mentioned above.  By default, RedisTemplate uses Java serialization for the keys, so they don't end up in Redis as plain Strings (though if you do a template.opsForValue().get("person") you should get back a result since the same serialization happens to the key on get).  For example, if I do a "keys *" via redis-cli after executing your code, the "person" key is actually listed as "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x06person".